# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.label1'

Tags: c#, methods

I want to reuse a piece of code, so I figured I'll make a class with a method that contains that code, and then I'll just call the method wherever I need it.

I've made a simple example of what my problem is:

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadText.getText();
        }
    }
}
```

**LoadText.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class LoadText : Form1
    {
        public static void getText()
        {
            WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.label1.Text = "New label1 text";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I've got one form with a label, and I want to use my other method (getText in LoadText) to change the text of the label.

Here's my error message:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.label1'**

I've already changed **label1** from private to public under design.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Form1` is a class, not an object. `label1` is not a static member of the class, it is a member of the *instance* of `Form1`. Hence the error, which tells you that an object instance (of the `Form1` class) is required.

Try the following:

**Form1.cs:**

```
LoadText.getText(label1);
```

**LoadText.cs:**

```
public static void getText(Label lbl)
{
    lbl.Text = "New label1 text";
}
```

You now have a static method that will accept a `Label` object and set its text to "new label1 text".

See the following link for further information on the `static` modifier:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

HTH

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem for newcomers to OO programming.

If you want to use a method of an object, you need to create an instance of it (using new). UNLESS, the method doesn't require the object itself, in which case it can (and should) be declared static.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to your form in order to access its elements.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different method that worked also:

**Form1.cs:**

```
 // here a static method is created to assign text to the public Label
 public static void textReplaceWith(String s, Label label)
 {
     label.Text = s;
 }
```

**LoadText.cs:**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class LoadText : Form1
    {
        //new label declared as a static var
        public static Label pLabel;

        //this method runs when your form opens
        public LoadTextForm() 
        {
            pLabel = Label1; //assign your private label to the static one
        }

        //Any time getText() is used, the label text updates no matter where it's used
        public static void getText()
        {
           Form1.textReplaceWith("New label1 text", pLabel); //Form1 method's used 
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to use a public method to change the text variable for your label from just about anywhere. Hope this helps :)